# Spring MVC throws 404 with normal request mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Currently I am running the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, path = "/addComment/:id")
public Ticket addComment(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id, @RequestBody AddCommentRequest comment) {
    Ticket ticket = repository.findOne(id);
    ticket.addComment(comment.message);
    return repository.save(ticket);
}
```

This throws me into a 404 not found error.

Can anyone help me solving this little issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a URL pattern like the following:

```
/addComment/{id}
```

Therefore your code should be like below:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, path = "/addComment/{id}")
public Ticket addComment(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id, @RequestBody AddCommentRequest comment) {
    Ticket ticket = repository.findOne(id);
    ticket.addComment(comment.message);
    return repository.save(ticket);
}
```

I hope that this can help you.

Comment: It seems that it solves the 404 problem! Thankyou :>